# Python Regex to find c# style strings that contain Greek text

Tags: c#, python, regex

I am developing a python script to find c# strings that contains Greek letters in .cs code files . The regular expression i use is :

```
\"(?:[^\"\\]+|\\.)*[Ά-ϛ](?:[^\"\\]+|\\.)*\"
```

It performs well for online regex debuggers but when used in script it causes backtracking my code to pause. How can i improve upon this regex

Comment: Remove the inner `+`: `\"(?:[^\"\\]|\\.)*[Ά-ϛ](?:[^\"\\]|\\.)*\"`, or unroll it like `\"[^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*[Ά-ϛ][^\"\\]*(?:\\.[^\"\\]*)*\"`